# Why does creating a histogram in lightgbm help make the algorithm faster?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

Let us say you input sorted data.

1. To find the split in the case of a non-histogram-based approach, You would go through every possible split. O(#data)
2. To find the split in the case of the histogram-based approach, you would first build the histogram (O(#data)) and then find the split (O(#bins)). So, overall O(#data + #bins)

How is 2 faster than 1? The [official explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Features.rst#optimal-split-for-categorical-features:%7E:text=Reduced%20cost%20of%20calculating%20the%20gain%20for%20each%20split) is

- Pre-sort-based algorithms have time complexity O(#data)
- Computing the histogram has time complexity O(#data), but this involves only a fast sum-up operation. Once the histogram is constructed, a histogram-based algorithm has time complexity O(#bins), and #bins is far smaller than #data.

What is a **fast sum-up operation** mentioned above?